# Bound value in a conditional binding must be of optional type

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting an error on the line `if let randNumber = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count))` that says

> Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type.

I may be wrong but I think I have to change the UInt32 value to an optional value, but if that's the case how do I do that? If not then what is it I need to change exactly to be of an Optional type?

```
    var query = PFQuery(className: "VoteCount")
    query.countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (count: Int32, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if let randNumber = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count)) {
                println("The random object is \(randNumber)\")
            }
        } else {
            println("error \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The return type of `arc4random_uniform` is `UInt32` rather than `UInt32?` so there no need for the conditional. So you can just go with:

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "VoteCount")
query.countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (count: Int32, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        let randNumber = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count))
        println("The random object is \(randNumber)")
    } else {
        println("error \(error)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this please

```
let randNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(count))
```

Answer (score -1):

> In some cases, you might be absolutely certain that an Objective-C
>   method or property never returns a nil object reference. To make
>   objects in this special scenario more convenient to work with, Swift
>   imports object types as implicitly unwrapped optionals. Implicitly
>   unwrapped optional types include all of the safety features of
>   optional types. In addition, you can access the value directly without
>   checking for nil or unwrapping it yourself. [[source]](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_31)

So you can do like :

```
if let randNumber = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count)) as UInt32!{ 
}
```